# How to pass data in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to pass `o_id` in data but when I try it show me error :

> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#assign").click(function(){
    params = ""
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() != "") {
            if(params != "") {
                params += "&";
            }
            params += $(this).data('id')+"="+$(this).text();
        }
    });
    if(params!="") {
          var o_id = <?php echo $o_id ?>;
        $.ajax({
            url: "assign_product.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:params+'&o_id'=o_id,
            success: function(response){
              $("#ajax-response").append(response);
              $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use `params+'&o_id=' + o_id,` Closing it as TYPO

Comment: thanks @satpal its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in this line:

```
data:params+'&o_id'=o_id,
```

The `=` sign must be inside the quotes.
This is because you have a message about `assignment`.

Answer (score 5):

You should pass the parameters as an object not a string, The `params` should be an object and you could append the key/value to this object :

```
var params = {};

$("td[contentEditable='true']").each(function(){
  if( $(this).text() != "" ) {
    params[ $(this).data('id') ] = $(this).text();
  }
});
```

You need also to replace :

```
if(params!="") {
```

By :

```
if( $.isEmptyObject(params) ){
```

To check if the object is empty.

**FULL CODE :**

```
$("#assign").click(function() {
  var params = {};

  $("td[contentEditable='true']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "") {
      params[$(this).data('id')] = $(this).text();
    }
  });

  if ($.isEmptyObject(params)) {
    params["o_id"] = <?php echo $o_id ?>;

    $.ajax({
      url: "assign_product.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: params,
      success: function(response) {
        $("#ajax-response").append(response);
        $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right @zakaria next time i will try with objects.

Comment: Need a different `if()` too now that you change to object

Comment: Yes true @charlietfl , thanks..

Answer (score -3):

this is not ok:  `data:params+'&o_id'=o_id,`
see the documentation and do not forget the `content-type` or `dataType`.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
Regards

Check this to json please:

```
var request = {CompanyDB: sapws.dbName, UserName: sapws.wsUser, Password: sapws.wsPass};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: sapws.wsUrl + "/Login",
                        contentType: "text/plain",
                        data: JSON.stringify(request),
                        async: false,
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: true,
                        },
                        //crossDomain: true,
                        beforeSend: function (req) {

                        },
                        success: function (jsonData, status, req) {

                            document.cookie = "B1SESSION=" + jsonData.SessionId + "; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
                            sapws.wsKey = jsonData.SessionId;

                            var response = sapws.slSend("GET", "/EmployeesInfo?$filter=U_AppUser eq '" + username + "' and U_AppPass eq '" + userpass + "' ", "");
                            if (response.value.length > 0) {
                                sapws.userLogin = 1;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data, status, req) {
                            console.log("error log2");
                            console.log(status, req);

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Ok, and how should he fix it?

Comment: Why content-type? OP is using default

Comment: Check the new example please!